# How to search for CJK characters by typing in their Latin counterpart and input them into a textbox in vb

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So, I'm making a Chinese input program and I would like the user to be able to search for a character, click it, and it will appear in a rich textbox. I have no clue to go about doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, i'm not entirely sure what you want your program to do, but from what I have understood is that you want to create something that converts simple letters in english to output in a Chinese language? 
If this is the case, you can create an array of characters, store them and assign them letters that correspond to the letters on the keyboard, create a textfield in which the user can input a letter and press a button to search your array for the correct corresponding letter.
For this you will have to get all the Chinese characters and know which letter they correspond to.
Good luck!

Comment: Just wondering, how would they search the array? Could you give an example if possible?

Comment: Try using linear search, easy and simple. Found tutorial for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1syvtC55e-Q

Comment: how would the program know how the word is spelled? Is there anyway I could add a "tag" Also, how could the user view multiple results?